# django openid "Error using OpenID"

Tags: django, openid, django-openid-auth

I am using django-openid from http://github.com/simonw/django-openid.
But no matter whatever openid i enter it gives out this error: "Error using OpenID", "The OpenID was invalid"

**Update**:
Got it to work with django-openid. It seems the error was because i was using localhost. So i had to create a local openid server to make it work.
Also i found out a better implementation of django openid, django-openid-auth hosted at https://launchpad.net/django-openid-auth.
A working example of django-openid-auth @ http://www.rohanjain.in/.

Comment: Im having the same problem but with some other openID library. Will hosting it up instead of using localhost work without any modifications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I have heard Django-openid is incomplete. You might want to try out [Django-Socialauth](http://github.com/agiliq/Django-Socialauth) instead. It supports OpenID and gives you a few other options as well.

Comment: Thanks will look at socialauth later, right now i got it working with django-openid-auth @ http://rohan.cz.cc/